# DeIndex a URL with a version ending in a hash bang

Tags: codeigniter, url, url-rewriting, duplicates, seo

I just want to deindex or remove the page ending with `#!`.
It is a dynamic page which fetching data from database and rendering on two URLs

- `example.com/detail/297#!`
- `example.com/detail/297`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deindex both of those URLs you should return a "410 Gone" HTTP status for them.  (Or even a "404 Not Found" status would work but it isn't as descriptive.)

If you want to deindex only the version with the hash bang, that is a little harder. URLs with the hash, share the same HTTP request, response, and status code as the version without the hash.  That means that handling the hash portion of the URL can only be done with JavaScript.  You will need to insert JavaScript into the page that detects that presence of the hash bang and implements one of the following:

- Changes the `location.href` to remove the hash bang
- Changes the `location.href` to the URL of a "410 Gone" error page
- Dynamically inserts a `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` tag into the `<head>` of the page.